# type() function doesn't return correct result for a boto3 sqs object?

Tags: python, boto, boto3, type-hinting, mypy

I'm using Python 3's type hinting syntax, and I'm writing a small AWS application that uses SQS. I'm trying to hint the type of the Queue. This is how I obtain the type of the Queue:

```
>>> import boto3
>>> session = boto3.session.Session(
>>>     aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
>>>     aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET_KEY,
>>>     region_name='us-west-2'
>>> )
>>> sqs = session.resource('sqs')
>>> queue=sqs.Queue(AWS_QUEUE_URL)
>>> 
>>> type(queue)
<class 'boto3.resources.factory.sqs.Queue'>
```

And I write my type-hinted function like this:

```
def get_session() -> boto3.resources.factory.sqs.Queue:
    ...
```

But I get an error:

```
AttributeError: module 'boto3.resources.factory' has no attribute 'sqs'
```

I've looked through the package myself using `dir(...)`. It seems that `factory` does not contain `sqs`, indeed. Thus, I have two questions:

- Why is `type` returning this nonexistent class?
- How can I find the right type of this object?

Comment: You have to `import boto3.resources.factory.sqs`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: I don't think that's actually a thing.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga ```>>> import boto3.resources.factory.sqs

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'boto3.resources.factory.sqs'; 'boto3.resources.factory' is not a package
>>> ```

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: [Here's `boto3/resources/factory.py`.](https://github.com/boto/boto3/blob/develop/boto3/resources/factory.py) You'll see that it's not a package, and it doesn't seem to define anything named `sqs`. I think this class is created dynamically.

Comment: I think this is just one of those cases where type hinting won't work and you shouldn't bother.

Comment: @user2357112 aha, you are correct. I was just guessing.

Comment: `boto3.resources.factory.ResourceFactory.load_from_definition()` does indeed create classes dynamically. I bet though that these are stored in a registry somewhere where they could possibly be retrieved from for type hinting purposes.

Comment: Yeah, these classes are generated on the fly. You'll need to use forward references to use type hinting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The class of `sqs.Queue` appears to be generated on the fly every time it's called:

```
>>> import boto3
>>> session = boto3.session.Session(aws_access_key_id='foo', aws_secret_access_key='bar', region_name='us-west-2')
>>> sqs = session.resource('sqs')
>>> sqs.Queue
<bound method sqs.ServiceResource.Queue of sqs.ServiceResource()>
>>> q = sqs.Queue('blah')
>>> type(q)
<class 'boto3.resources.factory.sqs.Queue'>
>>> q2 = sqs.Queue('bluh')
>>> type(q) == type(q2)
False
```

So that's kind of a bad design choice on boto's end. I think it means it's not possible to reasonably type annotate it, even with forward references.

Your best bet is to give a type hint for the common base class of all these dynamic classes, `boto3.resources.base.ServiceResource`:

```
>>> type(q).__bases__
(<class 'boto3.resources.base.ServiceResource'>,)
```

Comment: Works for me. What's the best type annotation I can do then? `queue: object`?

Comment: You can do `queue: boto3.resources.base.ServiceResource`